# What does $P(X=1)$ mean in probability theory and statistic?

Tags: probability-theory

$S$: a sample space.
$\mathcal{B}$: a sigma algebra on $S$.
$P$: a probability function from $\mathcal{B}\to \Bbb{R}$.
$X$: a random variable from $S$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

I saw $P(X=1)$ (and many this kind of notations) in many books in probability theory.

1. It is strange to write $X=1$ because $X$ is a function and $1$ is a number.
2. It is strange to substitute an equation "$X=1$" into the function $P$.
3. I think it means $P(\{s\in S\mid X(s)=1\})$, but I am not sure.

**My Question:** the notation $P(X=1)$ is just a notation for convenience (to stand for $P(\{s\in S\mid X(s)=1\})$) even it is not rigorous?

Comment: Short answer: yes.